# PHP CSV writing corrupt headers sporadically

Tags: php, csv

I have a class for writing CSV lines to a new file

```
fwrite($this->the_file_resource, implode($this->delimiter, $headers_array) . PHP_EOL);
```

When this runs on our application, every so often the data will write to the CSV file corrupted, I can run the same command immediately afterwards and it works completely as expected.

Expected:

[image]

Corrupt:

[image]

One thing I have noticed is that it's always the header and always in the first couple of columns.

What would the best method be to troubleshoot this? It's very difficult to replicate as it's not consistent.

Comment: What's in your $headers_array ?

Comment: "headers" => array(
                "SEQNBR",
                "REGION",
                "BUSINESS_UNIT",
                "DEPTID",
                "PRODUCT",
                "FISCAL_YEAR",
                "FISCAL_PERIOD",
                "POSTED_TOTAL_AMT",
                "ACCOUNT"
            )

Comment: Try to use utf8_encode

Comment: @SamB. Did your CSV files got corrupted again ? Or setting the header correctly fixed the bug?

Comment: Hey, sorry, things have been crazy lately. So the headers didn't work, I think there was some crazy thing happening with race conditions though, the application had 2 cron jobs running, one gathering this CSV file and the latter opening it and getting the content to push to another location. I think the handle was still open as the second process kicked off corrupting the file, I haven't seen it again since adding some padding to the cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header correctly before generating your CSV. Your problem looks like an encoding problem

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added that to my code and I'll report back if I see it again.

Comment: @SamB. No problem, hope it fixes your bug :).